# How to change the color of a Material Floating Action Button while being pressed?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design, floating-action-button

How can I change the color of the FAB while the button is being pressed? I don't see a property like `onPressed()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `app:rippleColor` in your layour or the `rippleColor` attribute in the FAB style.

Where `fab_ripple` should be a selector.

Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
      <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary" android:state_focused="true"/>
      <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary" android:state_hovered="true"/>
      <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary"/>

</selector>
```